# Overlapping letters

Tags: fonts, spacing, letterspacing

As I wrote in the title, I have a problem with two overlapping letters.
Namely, I have to write the word *flop* but when I write it latex overlaps the f and the l:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this overlapping from happening?

I'm sorry for the dimensions of the image, I wasn't able to make it larger.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The letters don't overlap, they combine into a [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)). You can suppress an individual ligature by adding `\/` between the letters, but in general your documents will look better if you keep them.

Comment: I see, thank you!